# How to size down the div, when i'm using smaller device? Displaying without scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have the div with specified width: 550px, to good display on desktop devices.
But when i use smaller device (like smartfon) with narrower screen, it's destroy my design of the site, because the div is not full-displayed - I must use the scrollbar.

How can I auto-scale the div to smaller size, when the width of the screen is less than 550px? I want to show full div on this device without scrollbar.

But when I'm using device with display-width more than 550px, div must have only 550px width.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-width and max-width in your css code.

```css
.test-div {
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
min-width: 150px;
max-width: 550px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="test-div">
  <h1>This is a Test</h1>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```